# Java How to create Bleeping dots?

Tags: java

I have a Java application where you can press a button and a missile is launched (represented by a red 5 x 5 pixel dot). The dot moves from point A to point B which is good.
What I want to know is how can I make the dot bleep like on a radar.
This is what I have so far:

```
public class Explosion {
    public int x, y, ex, ey, sx, sy;

    public String Country, target;

    private Image img;

    public boolean remove;

    public int time = 0;
    public int timer = 40;

    public Explosion(String Country, String target) {
        this.Country = Country;
        this.target = target;
        GetCoordsLaunch();
        GetCoordsTarget();
    }

    public void GetCoordsTarget() {
        if (target == "Ocean") {
            ex = play.mh.x + 4 + 140;
            ey = play.mh.y + 245 + 16;    
        }    
    }

    public void GetCoordsLaunch() {
        if (Country == "USA") {
            x = play.mh.x + 4 + 86;
            y = play.mh.y + 245 + 42;    
        }    
    }

    public void tick() {
        if (time >= timer) {
            if (x > ex) {
                x--;
            }
            if (x < ex) {
                x++;
            }
            if (y > ey) {
                y--;
            }
            if (y < ey) {
                y++;
            }

            time = 0;

        } else {

            time++;

        }
        if (x == ex && y == ey) {
            remove = true;
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "blinking"?

Comment: I had the same question, because bleep = a short high-pitched sound made by an electronic device as a signal or to attract attention according to Google translate.

Comment: Can you add the sections where `render` and `tick` are used?

Comment: I'm puking because of `target == "Ocean"` and `Country == "USA"`. **PLEASE**, compare Strings with .equals() !!! *sigh*

Comment: @Charlie Why not target.matches("Ocean")?

Answer (score 0):

You could have it paint only some portion of the `time`. Thus when time is within a certain range you paint, when it's not you don't. Thus it will paint on and off.

Try just changing render to depend on the time variable, only doing any drawing in the first half of the time frame. I'm also assuming that `timer` represents the number of ticks per movement

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    if(time < timer/2){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
    }
}
```

So if you're continuously `tick()`, this will paint on and off as it moves.